# RecyclerView doesn't update UI on Android 5.1.1

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, visibility

I have a issue that reprodusing only on Android 5.1.1 and few devices on 5.1. On the rest of versions works fine.

Recycler view have onClick listener whereI try to update View Visibility from GONE to VISIBLE or conversely. After clicking on item nothing changes on UI. 
**Note: If I close (BackButton) Fragment and open once again - UI will be updated. Even after pressing back button I see that UI updating for few milliseconds before destroing.**

I tryed to notify all adapter, current item, invalidate itemView, swap() and set adapter again without success.
All methods setVisibility(), onClick, Callbacks, BindView are successfully called (debugger).

```
public class PhotoGalleryAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PhotoGalleryAdapter.PhotoHolder> {

    private Context context;
    private List<String> photos;
    private View.OnClickListener listener;

    public PhotoGalleryAdapter(Context context, List<String> photos, View.OnClickListener listener) {
        this.context = context;
        this.photos = photos;
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    @Override
    public PhotoGalleryAdapter.PhotoHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_photo, parent, false);
        return new PhotoHolder(v, listener);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final PhotoGalleryAdapter.PhotoHolder holder, int position) {
        String photoPath = photos.get(position);
        Glide.with(context)
                .load(photoPath)
                .thumbnail(0.1f)
                .into(holder.image);

        if (Utils.getSelectedPhotos().contains(photoPath)) {
            DrawableCompat.setTint(holder.selection.getDrawable(), ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.white));
            holder.selection.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            holder.selection.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return photos.size();
    }

    public void updateDataSet(List<String> photos) {
        if (!photos.equals(this.photos)) {
            this.photos.clear();
            this.photos.addAll(photos);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }

    class PhotoHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

        @BindView(R.id.imageView) AppCompatImageView image;
        @BindView(R.id.selectionState) AppCompatImageView selection;

        private View.OnClickListener listener;

        PhotoHolder(View view, View.OnClickListener listener) {
            super(view);
            ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
            view.setOnClickListener(this);
            this.listener = listener;
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
           if (Utils.getSelectedPhotos().contains(photos.get(getAdapterPosition()))) {
                selection.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                Utils.getSelectedPhotos().remove(photos.get(getAdapterPosition()));
            } else {
                Utils.getSelectedPhotos().add(photos.get(getAdapterPosition()));
                DrawableCompat.setTint(selection.getDrawable(), ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.white));
                selection.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            listener.onClick(view);
        }
    }
}
```

And on callback:

```
 @Override public void onClick(View view) {
     callbacks.onPhotoSelected(Utils.getSelectedPhotos().size());
     adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); }
```

Comment: Are your support libraries up to date?

Comment: @TylerPfaff yes,  supportVersion = '27.0.0'

Comment: @ArsenBoikanych Ever come up with a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

According to your `PhotoGalleryAdapter` .

```
public void updateDataSet(List<String> photos) {
    if (!photos.equals(this.photos)) {
        this.photos.clear();
        this.photos.addAll(photos);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

And you use

```
if (Utils.getSelectedPhotos().contains(photoPath)) {
        DrawableCompat.setTint(holder.selection.getDrawable(), ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.white));
        holder.selection.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
} else {
        holder.selection.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

This line `Utils.getSelectedPhotos()` is not update .

And your problem is `callbacks.onPhotoSelected(Utils.getSelectedPhotos().size());` .

You can use `updateDataSet` to update UI .

When you click .And you can use like this .

```
Utils.setSelectedPhotos(yourList);
adapter.updateDataSet(yourList);
```

**Edit**

You should update your list first ,then use `notifyDataSetChanged` .

So you list did not update , you should check for it .

Comment: Not working. 
notifyDataSetChanged() working ok but UI (setVisibilty) still not working.

Comment: You should check your own code .`callbacks.onPhotoSelected(Utils.getSelectedPhotos().size());`

Comment: this code just return synchronized List<String>. I tried to use local (not static) with same results.

Comment: Good luck to you.@ArsenBoikanych

Answer (score 0):

**Update Solution:** after changing onClick to:

```
     @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
               if (Utils.getSelectedPhotos().contains(photos.get(getAdapterPosition()))) {
                    Utils.getSelectedPhotos().remove(photos.get(getAdapterPosition()));
                } else {
                    Utils.getSelectedPhotos().add(photos.get(getAdapterPosition()));
                }
                notifyDataSetChanged();
                listener.onClick(view);
            }
```

Works good, **BUT** only with LinearLayoutManager. Still doesn't works with GridLayoutManager.
So after calling setVisibility() twice Android works unpredictably.